# Generating word counts while sorting by order of appearance in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sorting

I am trying to sort a file of words in the order they appear in the file (I am only interested in certain words in the file). The first word appearing at the top of the output and the last word appearing at the bottom.

The usual way to generate a word count, with `sort | uniq -c`, eliminates sort order. How can I generate this frequency count without losing that ordering?

Sample text file:

> Godard conscious aioli Ouija Aeolus victorious furious perfect family twelve silver seven promiscuous radioactive one you Thursday heart Ate pizza contagious near princess ion water ace igneous ambitious

Sample output:

```
1 conscious 
1 aioli 
1 Ouija 
1 Aeolus 
1 victorious 
1 furious 
1 promiscuous 
1 radioactive 
1 contagious 
1 igneous 
1 ambitious
```

Comment: I'm making a program to read a file full of words. The program should output every word in the file with 3 vowels in it. I want to order the output so that the first word the file reads with 3 vowels is the first one outputted and so on

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Doesn't sound like there's any "sorting" at all -- it sounds like you **only** need to filter.

Comment: You just need `grep` then. `grep -i '^[^aeiou]*[aeiou][^aeiou]*[aeiou][^aeiou]*[aeiou][^aeiou]*$' file`

Comment: how would i do this filter in bash

Comment: What are the `1`s, by the way? Count? If so, provide sample data such that at least one of those counts is nonzero.

Comment: @glennjackman, ...hmm. I had to do a second take for a bit, but do suppose `[^aeiou]*` reduces the amount of possible backtracking as compared to `.*`, so would indeed make things more efficient with lousy regex engines.

Comment: yeah, that was when I though "3 vowels" meant the word contained *exactly* 3 vowels, not (as it turns out) "3 consecutive vowels".

Comment: @david8146, if a word is present twice, do you want to print it with `2` preceding twice (once corresponding with each location in the input), or only once (corresponding with the *first* location in the input only)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Part One: Extracting Matching Words

The following command:

```
s='Godard conscious aioli Ouija Aeolus victorious furious perfect family twelve silver seven promiscuous radioactive one you Thursday heart Ate pizza contagious near princess ion water ace igneous ambitious'
tr '[[:space:]]' '\n' <<<"$s" | egrep -i '[aeoiu].*[aeiou].*[aeiou]'
```

...generates the output:

```
conscious
aioli
Ouija
Aeolus
victorious
furious
promiscuous
radioactive
contagious
igneous
ambitious
```

...which properly contains the subset of words with at least three vowels, in their original order of appearance.

---

#### Part Two: Adding A Counter While Maintaining Sort Order

To maintain a counter requires either maintaining state or doing multiple passes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [[ -z $BASH_VERSION ]] || [[ $BASH_VERSION = [1-3].* ]]; then
  echo "ERROR: This requires bash 4.0 or newer" >&2
  exit 1
fi

### Begin code from Part 1
s='Godard conscious aioli Ouija Aeolus victorious furious perfect family twelve silver seven promiscuous radioactive one you Thursday heart Ate pizza contagious near princess ion water ace igneous ambitious'
get_words() { tr '[[:space:]]' '\n' <<<"$s" | egrep -i '[aeoiu].*[aeiou].*[aeiou]'; }
### End code from Part 1

declare -a var_order=( )
declare -A var_count=( )
while IFS= read -r var; do
  if (( ${var_count[$var]} )); then
    var_count[$var]=$(( ${var_count[$var]} + 1 ))
  else
    var_order+=( "$var" )
    var_count[$var]=1
  fi
done < <(get_words)

for var in "${var_order[@]}"; do
  printf '% -4d %s\n' "${var_count[$var]}" "$var"
done
```

...which properly generates the output:

```
 1   conscious
 1   aioli
 1   Ouija
 1   Aeolus
 1   victorious
 1   furious
 1   promiscuous
 1   radioactive
 1   contagious
 1   igneous
 1   ambitious
```

Comment: I want the words with 3 vowels in the order the words are seen in the file, not the order the vowels are. The order of the vowels within the word is irrelevant. If they have 3 vowels then they will be outputted e.g. contagious would be outputted. If contagious was the first word (that has 3 vowels) in the file  then I want it to be outputted first

Comment: @david8146, this already *is* in the order the words are seen in the file.

Comment: @david8146, ...look at your input file -- "Godard conscious aioli" is the order you provided. "Godard" is filtered out only because it doesn't have three vowels.

Answer (score 3):

`awk` to the rescue!

double scan to get the counts

```
$ awk -v RS=' +|\n' 'NR==FNR {t=$0; if(gsub(/[aeiou]/,"")>2) a[t]++; next} 
                     $0 in a {print a[$0],$0; delete a[$0]}' file{,}
1 conscious
1 aioli
1 Ouija
1 Aeolus
1 victorious
1 furious
1 promiscuous
1 radioactive
1 contagious
1 igneous
1 ambitious
```

from the sorted list extracted some other means, this will generate the counts based on the input sorting

```
 $ awk -v RS=' +|\n' '{t=$0} gsub(/[aeiou]/,"")>2{print t}' file | 
   # or some other means to generate filtered words ...
   cat -n        |     # add line number
   sort -k2 -k1n |     # sort by words and line number
   uniq -f1 -c   |     # find counts skipping line number
   sort -k2n     |     # sort by original line number
   awk '{print $1,$3}' # remove the line number
```

Comment: I really don't understand the one-liner culture in `awk`-land. Would it kill y'all to use whitespace and indentation? :P

Comment: added white space after `if()`, the rest is spaced fine.

Comment: Heh. Whereas if I were writing it, it'd look more like https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/1ae664cc2d32d36c7763865c3187e476 -- obvious where each statement or block begins and ends, plenty of vertical space to add comments on, etc.

Comment: Well, `--pretty-print` or `--profile` flags will generate it for you.  I type directly on the command line and copy/paste.  Obviously, will not work for longer scripts, but this is closer to one liner (OK, two liner).

Comment: (aside: current rev of the gist has each line annotated with a commented explanation; assuming it's accurate -- my awk's a bit rusty -- it might be of use to folks trying to follow or extend this answer).

Comment: It's very well commented, I would only change "if we *didn't* run the above block..." with "in the second iteration of the file for the selected words" but it's up to you.

Comment: I've amended that wording a bit; feel free to borrow/adopt the long-form version if so inclined. BTW, one thing that strikes me as potentially undesirable behavior is that if a word is present twice, we print it twice (with a `2` next to each). I've *assumed* that the OP only wants to print each word once (with the order of the first invocation indicating where)... but then, that *is* an assumption, and it probably bears followup in the question to figure out which interpretation is correct.

Comment: OK, yes that needs to be fixed.  Which I did.  Also added `\n` as record separator in case of multiple paragraphs.

Comment: Nice -- I would have gone with an uglier fix left to my own devices. Adopting the gist to match. :)

Answer (score 1):

I thought I should get in on this too.

Here's a one-liner, just for Charles:

```
gawk -v RS="[[:space:]]+" '{$0=tolower($0)} /[aeiou]{3}/ && !($0 in p) {p[$0]=n++} /[aeiou]{3}/ {a[p[$0]]=$0;c[p[$0]]++} END { for (i=0;i<n;i++) printf "%6d %s\n",c[i],a[i] }' input.txt
```

Broken out for easier reading (and commenting):

```
#!/usr/bin/env gawk -f

BEGIN {
  RS="[[:space:]]+"               # Set a reasonable record separator
}                                 # (includes spaces and newlines)

{
  $0=tolower($0)                  # ignore case...
}

/[aeiou]{3}/ && !($0 in p) {      # if we've found a word, make sure
  p[$0]=n++                       # we have a pointer to it.
}

/[aeiou]{3}/ {                    # if we've found a word and have a pointer,
  a[p[$0]]=$0                     # make a record of the word,
  c[p[$0]]++                      # and increment its counter.
}

END {                             # Once everything's been processed,
  for (i=0;i<n;i++)               # step through our list, and
    printf "%6d %s\n",c[i],a[i]   # print the results.
}
```

This covers multiple forms of whitespace, counts accurately, and keeps words in order. Oh, and it does this in a single pass.

Comment: Bravo for well-documented awk. :)

Answer (score 0):

Considering a more possible input

```
cat txt1
```

> Godard conscious aioli Ouija Aeolus victorious furious perfect family
>   twelve silver seven promiscuous radioactive one you Thursday ambitious
>   heart Ate pizza contagious near princess ion water ace ambitious
>   igneous ambitious conscious

below `awk` script would do the trick :

```
 awk 'NR==FNR {v[i++]=$0;c[$0]++;next}END{
  for(j=0;j<i;j++){if(p[v[j]]==0){print c[v[j]],v[j]}
  p[v[j]]=c[v[j]]>1?1:0;}
  }' <(awk -v RS=' +|\n' '$0 ~ /(.*[aAeEiIoOuU].*){3}/' txt1)
```

**Output**

```
2 conscious
1 aioli
1 Ouija
1 Aeolus
1 victorious
1 furious
1 promiscuous
1 radioactive
3 ambitious
1 contagious
1 igneous
```

Comment: I don't understand that the vowels need to be *in a row* -- while the question is presently quite vague, my read is only that the correct number of vowels needs to be present, even if not contiguous.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Like `AQUIB` where vowels are not in a row?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Hmm. There is a small change though, the `sed` substitution should be global, so added the `g` flag. Also considering the fact that I'm hardcoding newline in `sed` there are portability issues too.

Answer (score 0):

In plain bash, you could do:

```
set -f
shopt -s nocasematch
for word in $(< words.txt); do 
    [[ $word == *[aeiou][aeiou][aeiou]* ]] && echo $word
done
```

That just prints out the words with 3 consecutive vowels, it does not count them.

Comment: I'd argue that getting the count without disrupting ordering is the hard/interesting part of the question. :)